# Rails 3: What is the best way to update a column in a very large table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rake

I want to update all of a column in a table with over 2.2 million rows where the attribute is set to null. There is a Users table and a Posts table. Even though there is a column for num_posts in User, only about 70,000 users have that number populated; otherwise I have to query the db like so:

```
@num_posts = @user.posts.count
```

I want to use a migration to update the attributes and I'm not sure whether or not it's the best way to do it. Here is my migration file:

```
class UpdateNilPostCountInUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    nil_count = User.select(:id).where("num_posts IS NULL")

    nil_count.each do |user|
      user.update_attribute :num_posts, user.posts.count
    end
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

In my console, I ran a query on the first 10 rows where num_posts was null, and then used puts for each user.posts.count . The total time was 85.3ms for 10 rows, for an avg of 8.53ms. 8.53ms*2.2million rows is about 5.25 hours, and that's without updating any attributes. How do I know if my migration is running as expected? Is there a way to log to the console %complete? I really don't want to wait 5+ hours to find out it didn't do anything. Much appreciated.

**EDIT:** 
Per Max's comment below, I abandoned the migration route and used find_each to solve the problem in batches. I solved the problem by writing the following code in the User model, which I successfully ran from the Rails console:

```
def self.update_post_count
    nil_count = User.select(:id).where("num_posts IS NULL")
    nil_count.find_each { |user|
        user.update_column(:num_posts, user.posts.count) if user.posts
    }
end
```

Thanks again for the help everyone!

Comment: a quick google brings up https://github.com/ondrejbartas/rake-progressbar. It's old but worth a try.

Comment: [find_each](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) is better in situations like these, otherwise the process could be killed by timeout and the query results are handled better - to check the progress you could simply query the DB directly (or with a GUI) to count the remaining results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
desc 'Update User post cache counter'
task :update_cache_counter => :environment do

  users = User.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN "posts" ON "posts.user_id" = "users.id"')
              .select('"users.id", "posts.id", COUNT("posts.id") AS "p_count"')
              .where('"num_posts" IS NULL')

  puts "Updating user post counts:"
  users.find_each do |user|
    print '.'
    user.update_attribute(:num_posts, user.p_count)
  end
end
```

First off don't use a migration for what is essentially a maintenance task. Migrations should mainly alter the schema of your database. Especially if it is long running like in this case and may fail midway resulting in a botched migration and problems with the database state.

Then you need to address the fact that calling `user.posts` is causing a N+1 query and you instead should join the posts table and select a count.

And without using [batches](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html) you are likely to exhaust the servers memory quickly.

Comment: You may be able to do this with `.update_all` instead as a single SQL query with a subselect. I have done it with Postgres but unsure how to do it with MySQL. It would likely reduce the running time to seconds or minutes.

Comment: Thanks max. My problem is now solved. Additionally, I renamed the question and edited it to be more useful for others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `update_all` and `subquery` to do this.

```
sub_query = 'SELECT count(*) FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`'
User.where('num_posts IS NULL').update_all('num_posts = (#{sub_query})')
```

It will take only seconds instead of hours.
If so, you may not have to find a way to log something.